# how to get key as words in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have this dictionary how can I do to get the key instead value but reading words.
Example if I write 2 22 1 response must be A B .

```
value= {"A": 2, "B": 22, "C": 222, "D": 3, "E": 33,"F":333, "G": 4, "H": 44, "I": 444, "J": 5, "K": 55, "L": 555, "M": 6, "N": 66, "O": 666, "P": 7, "Q": 77, "R": 777, "S": 7777, "T": 8, "U": 88, "V": 888, "W": 9, "X": 99, "Y": 999, "Z": 9999}
```

I was trying with this loop but there´s something wrong:

```
for i in r:
  key= n[i]
  print key
```

Comment: This is not the way you use a dictionary.

Comment: I know but I can´t figure out how to use a list or a tuple with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse the dictionary:

```
value= {"A": 2, "B": 22, "C": 222, "D": 3, "E": 33,"F":333, "G": 4, "H": 44, "I": 444, "J": 5, "K": 55, "L": 555, "M": 6, "N": 66, "O": 666, "P": 7, "Q": 77, "R": 777, "S": 7777, "T": 8, "U": 88, "V": 888, "W": 9, "X": 99, "Y": 999, "Z": 9999} 
new_value = {b:a for a, b in value.items()}
print(new_value[2])
```

Output:

```
A
```

Regarding your latest comment, you can try this:

```
final_results = [a for a, b in value.items() if b == 22]
```

Comment: Caveat: the values must be unique, or you will overwrite early entries.

Comment: but if it´s a large string it doesn´t work, only read the first character

Comment: @apk what do you mean by large string? A string that does not exist in the values or keys?

Comment: if I type '22' the response is only 'A' not 'B'

Comment: @apk I made an edit to fix the list based solution. However, when I tried `new_value[22]` the program did indeed output 'B'

Comment: thanks, don´t have the answer to my question but you gave me an idea